# Umlauts in terminal-notifier MacOS

Tags: macos, command-line, bash, bash-scripting, gui

OSX-Mojave. I have a simple script:

```
#!/bin/bash

key="..."
text="$(echo $(pbpaste) | sed "s/[\"\'<>]//g")"
translate="$(/usr/local/bin/wget -qO - "https://translate.yandex.net/api/v1.5/tr.json/translate?key=$key&text=$text&lang=ru")"
echo $translate | sed 's/.*\[\"\(.*\)\"\].*/\1/' | /usr/local/bin/terminal-notifier -title "$text" -subtitle "$translate"
```

Script work without any problem and translate content from a clipboard if was fired from a terminal. I would like to bind the script to keyboard hotkey. Did with automator, but in popup from (terminal-notifier) I do not see umlauts and that's why translation is wrong. I thought, that that problem somewhere with automatator, I compiled simple app with osascript where I starting my bash script and binded to hotkey without automator, but still the same problem. If start the app or bash script from cli, in popup I see umlauts and correct translation. But with hotkey I see the problem with umlauts again.

Could please someone explain me, where is a problem or where to search the errors. Thank you in advance!

[image]

[image]

Comment: First step is to inspect the API reply for encoding type, and if it's UTF-8 etc., see how the special characters are represented (single code points? combiners?), e.g. with `hexdump -C ...`. It looks like I need an API key for this URL, so I can't try for you. Next step is to figure out what encoding `terminal-notifier` needs, and to convert if necessary.

Comment: I do not understand, why starting from terminal shows correct output, but start on hotkey from GUI shows broken output